# Create and Send Paypal Invioce in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am working on a project using Codeigniter framework. There is a button of a product(that is currently store in database), when user click on Order button, here i want to create and send Paypal invoice from my system, according to price.

I have also created developer account on paypal site. I have search the following links.

http://www.angelleye.com/demo/codeigniter/paypal/adaptive_payments/
http://askimran.wordpress.com/2009/10/09/paypal-integration-using-codeigniter-phase1/
https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/how-use-paypal-invoicing-apis-php

I am confused after reading all these. Could you please help me with step by step tutorial for the paypal integration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically are you having problems understanding?